# glossaries and REnewglossaryentry

Tags: macros, glossaries

I haven't found anywhere and I wonder is there or would it be very hard to provide a command `\REnewglossaryentry[2]` for the `glossaries` package.

Name for the ***desired command*** is kinda *self explanatory*, but bellow is a wanna-be-MWE of what I am looking to achieve:

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn,oneside,openright]{book}
\pagestyle{plain} 

\usepackage[%
    xindy,%
    acronym,%
    toc=true,%
    shortcuts,%
    style=altlist,
    sanitize={%
        name=false,%
        description=false,%
        symbol=false%
        }%
    ]{glossaries}    

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{somethingGloss}{
    name            = {something},
    description     = {some\ldots{} description},
    sort            = {something}
}

\newglossaryentry{aSTH}{
    type            = {\acronymtype},
    name            = {aSTH{\protect\glsadd{electroencephalographyGloss}\protect\index{electroencephalography}}},
    first           = {a something (STH){\protect\glsadd{electroencephalographyGloss}\protect\index{electroencephalography}}},
    description     = {some\ldots{} description},
    see             = [see Glossary:]{somethingGloss},
    sort            = {aSTH}
    }

% % % % % % 
\newcommand{\REnewglossaryentry}[2]{%
    some serious stuff here%
    to REset the the key-val list%
    for a label given!}

\begin{document}

    \glsaddall

    \gls{aSTH}, subsequent \gls{aSTH} is \gls{somethingGloss} 

    \REnewglossaryentry{label}{new key-val list}

    % % % % % % 
    \REnewglossaryentry{aSTH}{ % % % command desired to REset the key-val list!
        type            = {\acronymtype},
        name            = {aSTH{\protect\index{electroencephalography}}},
        first           = {a something (STH)}},
        description     = {some\ldots{} NEW description},
        see             = [see Glossary:]{somethingGloss},
        sort            = {aSTH}
        }

    \printglossary

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

    \REnewglossaryentry{somethingGloss}{new key-val list} % allow to
    % change the properties for the somethingGloss to be shown
    % in the new occurence of the glossary
    % (sort of a test for the \REnewglossaryentry)

    \printglossary

\end{document}
```

Using `name            = {aSTH{\protect\glsadd{electroencephalographyGloss} \protect \index{electroencephalography}}},` saves a lot of typing hassle in the document body but gets me into serious trouble when typesetting the **Glossary**

I have tried to produce a minimal example of that trouble, but (contrary) this little-awkward-bastard worked fine, opposite to what my document does when I introduce the `\protect\glsadd{...}` in the `name` key. In such case typically page numbers for the references inside of the **Glossary** are getting all twisted and screwed. And one doesn't really need the extra cross-reference functionality in the glossary since we have the `see=` key and the `\glshyperlink{}` available...

Therefore updating at least `name=` and `first=` for an entry (label) just before printing of the **Glossaries** would alleviate problems with cross-reference-loops, etc.

Also, I think that such command may provide various other usability benefits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this can't be done as it will interfere with the indexing process. In order to explain this, let's consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={Sample},%
  description={A sample description},%
  symbol={\textbf{S}}%
}

\begin{document}

% Page 1
\gls{sample}.

\newpage
% Page 2
\gls{sample}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Each time an entry is referenced using a command like `\gls` a line is written to the `.glo` file. By the end of the document, the `.glo` file contains a list of `\glossaryentry` lines. The above example generates a file that contains the following:

```
\glossaryentry{Sample?\glossaryentryfield{sample}{\glsnamefont{Sample}}{A sample description}{\textbf {S}}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{1}
\glossaryentry{Sample?\glossaryentryfield{sample}{\glsnamefont{Sample}}{A sample description}{\textbf {S}}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{2}
```

The indexing application (`makeindex` in this case) parses this file and collects the information in each `\glossaryentry{`*term*`}{`*location*`}`. All the entries with the same *term* part are collated into a single entry. The call to `makeindex` (either explicitly or implicitly via `makeglossaries`) creates the `.gls` file that contains the code for the glossary. The above example produces this:

```
\glossarysection[\glossarytoctitle]{\glossarytitle}\glossarypreamble
\begin{theglossary}\glossaryheader
\glsgroupheading{S}\relax \glsresetentrylist %
\glossaryentryfield{sample}{\glsnamefont{Sample}}{A sample description}{\textbf {S}}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
        \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1\delimN 2}}}%
\end{theglossary}\glossarypostamble
```

It's this file that is read in by `\printglossaries`. Any change to the term's name, description or symbol will have no effect on how it is displayed in the glossary, because the original name, description and symbol are explicitly written in the `.gls` file.

Now suppose that on page 3 the name of the term is changed to, say, `New Sample` and another `\gls{sample}` is used. This means that at the end of the run the `.glo` file now looks like:

```
\glossaryentry{Sample?\glossaryentryfield{sample}{\glsnamefont{Sample}}{A sample description}{\textbf {S}}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{1}
\glossaryentry{Sample?\glossaryentryfield{sample}{\glsnamefont{Sample}}{A sample description}{\textbf {S}}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{2}
\glossaryentry{Sample?\glossaryentryfield{sample}{\glsnamefont{New Sample}}{A sample description}{\textbf {S}}|setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat}{3}
```

From the point of view of `makeindex`, there are now two distinct entries in the glossary and it will list them separately like this:

```
\glossarysection[\glossarytoctitle]{\glossarytitle}\glossarypreamble
\begin{theglossary}\glossaryheader
\glsgroupheading{S}\relax \glsresetentrylist %
\glossaryentryfield{sample}{\glsnamefont{Sample}}{A sample description}{\textbf {S}}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
        \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{1\delimN 2}}}%
\glossaryentryfield{sample}{\glsnamefont{New Sample}}{A sample description}{\textbf {S}}{\glossaryentrynumbers{\relax 
        \setentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{3}}}%
\end{theglossary}\glossarypostamble
```

So you now get both "Sample" and "New Sample" in the glossary.

If you use `xindy` rather than `makeindex` the format of the `.glo` file is different, but the principle (and result) is the same.

From what I can gather from your question, your concern arises from a problem caused by having `\glsadd` or `\index` in the name in the glossary. In which case, why not just use those commands in the `text` field and omit them in the `name` field. For example:

```
\newglossaryentry{aSTH}{
    type            = {\acronymtype},
    text            = {aSTH{\protect\glsadd{electroencephalographyGloss}\protect\index{electroencephalography}}},
    name            = {aSTH},
    first           = {a something (STH){\protect\glsadd{electroencephalographyGloss}\protect\index{electroencephalography}}},
    description     = {some\ldots{} description},
    see             = [see Glossary:]{somethingGloss},
    sort            = {aSTH}
    }
```

Comment: comprehensive :D

Comment: btw, this is parallel what i have done last night --- I have used `user1=` with the same content as `name=` but with the additional commands.

I have used `user1=` because I think I don't understand quite well the purpose and functionality of `text=`.

Is it prioritized in any way (over other keys)?

When not assigned a value explicitly is it getting its value from `name=` or `symbol=`?

Will that be a decent and complying with _best practices_ if I define entry with `text=Ω`, `name=ohm` and `symbol=Ω`?

And then is it any difference to call for it with either `\gls{ohm}` `\glssymbol{ohm}`

Comment: @NeuroTeX The value of `text` defaults to the value of `name`. The `name` value is used in the glossary and via commands like `\glsentryname`. The `text` value is used by `\gls` (after first use) and `\glsentrytext`. The difference between using `text` and `symbol` comes with the difference between using `\gls` (varies according to first and subsequent use) and `\glssymbol` (always displays the `symbol` value).

Comment: Thank you kindly for your explanation and for your patience :)